# SQL Query in Access Syntax

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to translate this query to Access: The main challenge I am having is the Count column- it gives and error: Syntax Error(missing Operator) in Expression "Count....."
You will notice some of the changes already in the query- but the Count expression is killing me.

```
SELECT TblFacility.StrFacilityName,
       TblActivityGroup.GroupID,
       TblActivityGroup.StrGroupName,
       Count(TblClientActivities.ClientID) Over(
          Partition By tblFacility.StrFacilityName, 
                       TblActivityGroup.GroupID, 
                       TblActivityGroup.strGroupName 
          Order By tblFacility.StrFacilityName, 
                   TblActivityGroup.GroupID
      ) AS CountOfClientID
  FROM TblFacility
 INNER JOIN TblActivityGroup
 INNER JOIN TblClientActivities
    ON TblActivityGroup.GroupID = TblClientActivities.lngActivityGroup
   and TblFacility.StrFacilityID = TblClientActivities.lngLocation
 Where TblClientActivities.DtmDate Between Now() And
       DateAdd('m', -3, Now());
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Scott

Comment: I'm pretty sure this piece isn't needed.

Over (Partition By tblFacility.StrFacilityName, TblActivityGroup.GroupID, TblActivityGroup.strGroupName Order By tblFacility.StrFacilityName, TblActivityGroup.GroupID)

And you'd need a group by at the bottom.

Comment: Access doesn't support window functions like `Over()`. Use a `group by`

Comment: I agree w/ Utrolig, probably no point in the window function, rather than get rows repeated w/ a counter of 1, 2, 3, 4... you could just get the total count of 4 on one row. Ie. you'd get the count for each unique combination of (facilityname, groupid, strroupname)

Comment: Also you don't appear to have any join conditions between TblFacility and TblActivityGroup

Comment: `Between Now() And DateAdd('m', -3, Now());` Does this work? Between now and 3 months back ???

Comment: @JorgeCampos . . . It "works", but no dates can satisfy the condition.  That suggests that simply replacing the `where` clause with `1 = 0` would be equivalent.

Comment: @GordonLinoff My question was exactly that. Whats the point of that filter if it means to bring nothing. :)

Comment: Ok- sorry was offline- let's clarify a couple of things.
  The filter is to show every class between the current date and the last 3 months.  The Over partition is to keep me from having to repeat this query with multiple criteria.  In Access I need the date in the query in order to make it a criteria- it does not work like SQL in that aspect.  The joins were the result of Query Designer not direct programming.

Comment: Please help with anything you can.  The ultimate Goal is to count all of the attendance by each group within the previous 3 months.  I then have to do it for the 3 months prior, and 3 months before that.  I maybe totally missing something and if I am please let me know what it is.